# Outlook webaddin - Issue with Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync for shared mailbox

Tags: reactjs, office365, outlook-web-addins

I'm encountering an issue with the `Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync` function in my Office Add-in from office 365. The function works fine for a non-shared inbox but returns an error for a shared inbox.

Below is the code I am using

```
Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync(
            { isRest: true },
            (result: any) => {
                
                if (result.status === "succeeded") {
                    var accessToken = result.value;
                    console.log(accessToken);
                    this.getWebUrl()
                        .then((itemId) => {

                            
                } else {
                    
                    reject(result);
                    
                }
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Error Message:

> OSF.DDA.Error {name: 'GenericTokenError', message: 'An internal error has occurred.', code: 9018}

- Scenario: Works for non-shared inbox, but fails for Shared inbox.
- Expected Outcome: Successful retrieval of access token for shared inbox.

Questions:

- Has anything changed with `"getCallbackTokenAsync"` recently that might affect its behavior with shared inboxes?
- Are there specific permissions or configurations required for accessing shared mailboxes using "getCallbackTokenAsync"?

Can anyone please suggest any solution to this or anything that would help me resolve this?

Comment: We're getting the exact same issue. Works fine on the user's mailbox and also mail enabled groups, but fails in this manner on a shared mailbox. Unfortunately we have not yet found a solution.

Comment: @Equalsk 
Thank you for sharing your insights.
Was the "getCallbackTokenAsync" function working as expected for shared mailboxes in the past for you? Have you observed if this issue with shared mailboxes is a recent occurrence, or has it been a longstanding challenge ?

Comment: This is the first time we've tried to use this code. Our research suggested that it used to work. It's been accepted as a bug by Microsoft: [link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3748). After making this comment the code started working for us and we don't know why. If we figure it out I'll post the answer here.

Comment: @Equalsk oh it's surprising that it's working for you now. Sure. Thanks